# Erro ao efetuar um filtro com SQL

Tags: php, sql

Não consigo identificar o erro que está acontecendo no código abaixo:

```
$bannerguia=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, senha FROM conta WHERE senha = '$senhalog'");
while($painel_banner=mysqli_fetch_array($bannerguia))
{
     $issenha = $painel_banner['senha'];
     $isid = $painel_banner['id'];
}
```

No SQL quando eu coloco a variável `$senhalog` entre aspas `'$senhalog'` não funciona o filtro, se não coloco entre aspas funciona, mas dá erro se não localizar nada.

Em todos os sistemas que desenvolvo coloco entre aspas e tudo funciona perfeitamente, não entendi o que está acontecendo aqui.

Comment: Da um echo na query para ver como esta saindo o retorno.

Comment: Verifique se a variável `$senhalog` está com o valor correto, se estiver teste o sql direto no terminal ou phpmyadmin ou workbench ou algo assim, o erro pode estar no sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pensa comigo, você disse *"se não localiza nada sem aspas dá erro"*, se eu entendi o não localiza nada seria `$senhalog`? Se sim com certeza vai dar erro pois o select gerado será:

```
SELECT id, senha FROM conta WHERE senha =
```

e isso dá erro em qualquer banco.

Se a senha for tipo string vai precisar de aspas se não for faz um if ternario na variável dizendo que se tiver valor é ele senão coloca algo como null(não faz sentido esse $senhalog não existir).

Answer (score 1):

Coloque suas consultas em variáveis dessa forma você terá mais controle do resultado.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, senha FROM conta WHERE senha ='".$senhalog."';";
    //echo $sql;
    $bannerguia=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($painel_banner=mysqli_fetch_array($bannerguia))
    {
         $issenha = $painel_banner['senha'];
         $isid = $painel_banner['id'];
    }
?>
```